Malliavin calculus for the regularity of the density of the supremum of a process
I am reading Chapter 2 from Nualart's book 'The Malliavin calculus and related topics'.
Proposition 2.1.10 gives the conditions for the law of the supremum of a process to have a density. Condition (ii) requires ${DX(t), t \in S}$ to possess a continuous version.
I want to apply this Proposition for a solution to an SPDE $u(t,x)$, in order to show that the law of the supremum of $u(t,x)$ has a density.
I am stuck at the part of showing that $Du$ possesses a continous version. I am thinking of applying the Kolmogorov criterion, but I am confused about what I would need to show exactly.It seems to me that I would need to show the following for the Malliavin derivative $D_{s,y}u(t,x)$:
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s,y} u(t',x')|^{p}] \leq C \left( |t-t'|^{\alpha}+|x-x'|^{\beta} \right)
$$
for some exponents $p,\alpha,\beta$.
I am not sure if this is correct. Does $(s,y)$ need to vary as well? Would I need to show this instead:
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s',y'} u(t,x)|^{p}] \leq C \left( |s-s'|^{\alpha}+|y-y'|^{\beta} \right)
$$
or perhaps this:
$$
E[ |D_{s,y} u(t,x)- D_{s',y'} u(t',x')|^{p}] \leq C \left( |s-s'|^{\alpha}+|y-y'|^{\beta}+|t-t'|^{\gamma}+|x-x'|^{\delta} \right)
$$
for $Du$ to have a continuous version as required by the Proposition?
I am copying the Proposition and its proof here below for reference. Thank you all in advance!
Proposition 2.1.10 in Nualart:
Let $X=\{X(t), t \in S\}$ be a continuous process parametrized by a compact metric space $S$. Suppose that
(i) $E\left(\sup _{t \in S} X(t)^{2}\right)<\infty$;
(ii) for any $t \in S, X(t) \in \mathbb{D}^{1,2}$, the $H$-valued process $\{D X(t), t \in S\}$ possesses a continuous version, and $E\left(\sup _{t \in S}\|D X(t)\|_{H}^{2}\right)<\infty$.
Then the random variable $M=\sup _{t \in S} X(t)$ belongs to $\mathbb{D}^{1,2}$.
Proof: Consider a countable and dense subset $S_{0}=\left\{t_{n}, n \geq 1\right\}$ in $S$. Define $M_{n}=\sup \left\{X\left(t_{1}\right), \ldots, X\left(t_{n}\right)\right\}$. The function $\varphi_{n}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi_{n}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)=\max \left\{x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right\}$ is Lipschitz. Therefore, from Proposition 1.2.4 we deduce that $M_{n}$ belongs to $\mathbb{D}^{1,2}$. The sequence $M_{n}$ converges in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ to $M$. Thus, by Lemma 1.2 .3 it suffices to see that the sequence $D M_{n}$ is bounded in $L^{2}(\Omega ; H)$. In order to evaluate the derivative of $M_{n}$, we introduce the following sets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A_{1}= & \left\{M_{n}=X\left(t_{1}\right)\right\} \\
& \ldots \\
A_{k}= & \left\{M_{n} \neq X\left(t_{1}\right), \ldots, M_{n} \neq X\left(t_{k-1}\right), M_{n}=X\left(t_{k}\right)\right\}, \quad 2 \leq k \leq n
\end{aligned}
$$
By the local property of the operator $D$, on the set $A_{k}$ the derivatives of the random variables $M_{n}$ and $X\left(t_{k}\right)$ coincide. Hence, we can write
$$
D M_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{A_{k}} D X\left(t_{k}\right)
$$
Consequently,
$$
E\left(\left\|D M_{n}\right\|_{H}^{2}\right) \leq E\left(\sup _{t \in S}\|D X(t)\|_{H}^{2}\right)<\infty
$$
and the proof is complete.

For another reference that extends prop 2.1.10 see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18309053  "Distribution of the integral of maximum processes and applications". They explain that for each fixed r, one needs continuity of $G_{t}:=D_{r}X_{t}$.
